# Map/Recode numeric vector in R the simple/sane way

Tags: r, encoding, statistics

I would like to recode/map the columns (consists of `0:3`), then take a mean of the two columns.

```
d <- data.frame(v1=sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE), v2 = sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

So, the `revalue` in `plyr` complains, asking for factor or character values. Some points to using `match`, and some others points to use `as.string`. Vector are fist class citizen! I do *not* want to change them to something ridiculous just to remap which could have been done in a simple indexing with the map.

So, any simple *R way* to do it?

```
d <- data.frame(v1=sample(0:3, 5, replace = TRUE), v2 = sample(0:3, 5, replace = TRUE))

  v1 v2
1  3  2
2  3  1
3  0  3
4  0  1
5  0  0
```

I want it to be this: (use a map: `0:3 -> (0, 1, 0.5, -1)).

```
   v1 v2
1  -1  0.5
2  -1  1
3  0  -1
4  0  1
5  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your columns are all consecutive integers starting from 0, we can achieve this by "replacement by indexing". For example, for column `v1`, we can do

```
d$v1 <- c(0,1,0.5,-1)[d$v1 + 1]  ## add 1 so that index starts from 1 not 0
```

To apply this to all columns, we can use `lapply`:

```
replacement <- c(0,1,0.5,-1)
as.data.frame(lapply(d, function (x) replacement[x + 1]))
```

For your example data frame

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c(3,3,0,0,0), v2 = c(2,1,3,1,0))
```

It gives correct result as you expected:

```
#  v1   v2
#1 -1  0.5
#2 -1  1.0
#3  0 -1.0
#4  0  1.0
#5  0  0.0
```

---

> Let's imagine my column is a sample from `c(-1, 0, 99, 2.1)` to be mapped to `c(1, 5, -4, 99)`.

```
pool <- c(-1, 0, 99, 2.1)
replacement <- c(1, 5, -4, 99)
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(v1 = sample(pool, 5, TRUE), v2 = sample(pool, 5, TRUE))

#    v1   v2
#1  2.1 -1.0
#2  0.0  2.1
#3  0.0  2.1
#4 99.0 99.0
#5  2.1 99.0
```

We can use `match` to for replacement:

```
d$v1 <- replacement[match(d$v1, pool)]
```

Again, we use `lapply` to roll over columns:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(d, function (x) replacement[match(x, pool)]))

#  v1 v2
#1 99  1
#2  5 99
#3  5 99
#4 -4 -4
#5 99 -4
```

Comment: Please ignore consecutive nature of the example. A random integer sequence would be more general.

Comment: Let's imagine my column is a sample from (-1, 0, 99, 2.1) to be mapped to (1, 5, -4, 99).

Comment: As I understand it, match only returns the first occurrence. Do could it be a general solution? Also, I am astonishef that something as simple as this (one to one mapping between vectors) has such cryptic implementation in R.

Comment: I think because we are looping over using `lapply` with `match`, thus only need the first occurance anyway. This doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do it, though. The solution should scale with the size of the map, not the data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `if_val` function from [expss](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/) package (but I'm biased, since I'm the author).

```
library(expss)
set.seed(123)
d = data.frame(v1=sample(0:3, 5, replace = TRUE), v2 = sample(0:3, 5, replace = TRUE))
if_val(d, from = 0:3) = c(0, 1, 0.5, -1)

# or, with formula notation
set.seed(123)
d = data.frame(v1=sample(0:3, 5, replace = TRUE), v2 = sample(0:3, 5, replace = TRUE))
if_val(d) = c(0 ~ 0, 1 ~ 1, 2 ~ 0.5, 3 ~ -1)
```